# How to create separate JMS consumer and publisher spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am working on an consumer application which consumes from external Queue. For publishing messages there is different application.
Publisher application:
I have this interfaces and its implementation -

```java
public interface IRequest extends Serializable{
    void setMessageId(String messageId);
    String getMessageId();
   
    
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);

   
}
```

abstract class:

```java
public abstract class MyMessage implements IRequest {
    private String messageId;
    private Long id;
    //and getter and setter for above fields
}
```

implementation 1

```java
public class Mymessage1 extends MyMessage{
    //some implementation
}
```

implementation 2:

```java
public class Mymessage2 extends MyMessage{
    //some other implementation
}
```

publisher method

```java
public void publishToMessageTopic(IRequest message,String queueName) {
    logger.debug("Publishing message, id {} to MessageLogs Topic", message.getMessageId()); //queueName is "demoQueue"
    jmsTopicTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);

}
```

this is jms template bean

```java
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

this is messsage convertor

```java
@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());//set object mapper
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

Consumer application :
has same interface and it's implementation along with same JMS configuration as that of producer.
the listner is as follows:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "demoQueue", concurrency = "15",containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void processLogs(@Payload IRequest request) throws Exception {
    //some processing on request.
}
```

this is listner factory bean:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    return getJmsListenerContainerFactory(configurer, "10"); // default container
}
```

When I try to publish the message from publisher application it successfully publishes but on consumer side I can see exception as follows:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to resolve type id [com.model.Mymessage1]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.model.Mymessage1
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to avoid JMS `ObjectMessage` if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a package that is common to both projects.  This would typically include interfaces and implementation classes.  Your consumer has to know about `com.model.Mymessage1`, or am I missing something here?